# Screenreader Chromevox not reading element when focused

Tags: javascript, focus, accessibility

I can't work out how to get Chromevox read an element once you have changed focus to it via Javascript. Take the example found at [OpenAjax](http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/20/). When you click on the Show topic 1 button the controlled element is expanded and focus is moved to it. However in Chromevox it does not read the content of the element just the aria-labelledby.

To get Chromevox to read the content of the element after it has been expand I have to move out and back in again. Not a very good user experience.

Is this an issue to do with Chromevox or is there a better way to approach this?

Note: ignore the other three examples they have typos in their aria-labelledby attributes and thus don't function correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The ajax example is not a good one to mimic.  In addition to the t2/m2 typo you mentioned, they have competing labels.  There's a (hidden) `<div>` that contains text ("Topic 1 is all about being...") **and** there's an `aria-labelledby`.

According to the accessible name computation rules, https://www.w3.org/TR/accname-1.1/#step2, the `aria-labelledby` is processed in step 2.B.first-bullet and then the process is done.  The text inside the `<div>` should be ignored.

If there were **not** an `aria-labelledby`, then you would get to step 2.G and the inner text would be the accessible name (and read by a screen reader).

So, you are seeing/hearing a conflict and it may depend on the how the browser interprets these rules as to what text is read by the screen reader.

NVDA reads **both** the `aria-labelledby` and the text.

JAWS reads **only** the `aria-labelledby`, which is technically correct.

It sounds like Chromevox is doing the same thing as JAWS, which is correct.